# How do I read multiple JSON structures contained in one file?

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

I have a .txt file with this structure

```
section1#[{"p": "0.999834", "tag": "MA"},{"p": "1", "tag": "MO"},...etc...}]
section1#[{"p": "0.9995", "tag": "NC"},{"p": "1", "tag": "FL"},...etc...}]
...
section2#[{"p": "0.9995", "tag": "NC"},{"p": "1", "tag": "FL"},...etc...}]
```

I am trying to read it by using R with the commands

```
library(jsonlite)
data <- fromJSON("myfile.txt")
```

But I get this

```
Error in feed_push_parser(readBin(con, raw(), n), reset = TRUE) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       section2#[{"p": "0.99
                     (right here) ------^
```

How can I read it even by splitting by sections?

Comment: You probably need to manually read the files using `readLines`, remove the `section` part and then pass it to `fromJSON`.

Comment: What's generating such a file?

Comment: it comes from mySQL

Comment: What command do you run in mySQL that produces this crazy format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the prefix and bind the flattened JSON arrays together into a data frame:

```
raw_dat <- readLines(textConnection('section1#[{"p": "0.999834", "tag": "MA"},{"p": "1", "tag": "MO"}]
section1#[{"p": "0.9995", "tag": "NC"},{"p": "1", "tag": "FL"}]
section2#[{"p": "0.9995", "tag": "NC"},{"p": "1", "tag": "FL"}]'))

library(stringi)
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)

stri_replace_first_regex(raw_dat, "^section[[:digit:]]+#", "") %>% 
  map_df(fromJSON)
##          p tag
## 1 0.999834  MA
## 2        1  MO
## 3   0.9995  NC
## 4        1  FL
## 5   0.9995  NC
## 6        1  FL
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't create that file, it comes from public data. IT was exactly what I was afraid of, the json structure was not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `section#` from each line. Then your *.txt* will have a 2D array with JSON objects at each index.
You can access elements by accessing it as `foo[0][0]` being the first object of first line and `foo[m][n]` where `m` is the `number of sections -1` and `n` is `number of objects in each section -1`

Comment: Actually it still won't be a valid JSON file if you remove the prefix. A JSON file needs to have single root element. You'd need to have a wrapping `[ ]` and have `,` at the end of each line. It's more of a [JSON line](http://jsonlines.org/) format.

Comment: @MrFlick It won't be a JSON file, but it would be a 2D array.

Comment: Well, it's not a JSON array. Are you talking about reading in the data with `readLines()` or something? How are you paring this in R to make that a 2D array?

Comment: @MrFlick I am looking into it, will update my answer soon.

Comment: @Prateek Gupta. Thank you so much. I didn't create that file, it comes from public data. IT was exactly what I was afraid of, the json structure was not valid.